# Has many: display regions with 1 or more elements

Tags: laravel, relationship

I have relationship between adv and region model. Actually I want to display all regions which has one or more active adv (I have active column into adv). And next similar problem. All regions contain cities. When user choose some region into view he saw all cities from this region. What is the best way to do that?

I won't write manually every cities. I have 2 ideas:

1. first cities will be string column. Actually user will choose region and write name of city into input field.
2. controller will check that this city exist with this region. If not, it'll create a new.

I think that second idea is better because create search engine and filter results will be simpler.

Comment: Yes, second one is better to avoid duplicate city name in the table. Is it the only issue you have? Because you have also mentioned that you want to display all regions also with noe or more active adv.

Comment: Avoid dupliacate cities is simple becouse I (like an administrator) can change name of city.

Comment: Ok, what is the actual problem you are facing now? Please share with me.

Comment: First question is more important. I make mistake. But I don't know how I can edit that. This question is: "I want to display all regions which has one or more elements (adv). But we are considering only active adv."

Comment: So, you need a Eloquent query based on relation. Right?

Comment: Yes. I have relationship - Adv (belongsTo) and Region (hasMany)

Comment: I've answered. Please check and let me know if it is work for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a [global scope](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent#global-scopes) in your adv like this to filter to just active advs. (this will filter the advs in all eloquent queries)

Adv Model:

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Adv extends Model
{


    /**
     * The "booting" method of the model.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();

        static::addGlobalScope('aktiv', function (Builder $builder) {
            $builder->where('aktiv', '=', true);
        });
    }
}
```

And then use Relationship in the Region Model

```
namespace App\Models;

use Eloquent;

class Region extends Eloquent
{
    public function adv()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Adv');
    }
}
```

And Get the results in your controller:

```
$region = Region::has('adv')->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 Models

1. Region ( has many Adv)
2. Adv ( brlongs to Region)

1) Region.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Eloquent;

class Region extends Eloquent
{
    protected $table = "region";

    public function regionadv()
    {
        /*For active adv only*/
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Adv')->where('active', '=', 1);
    }

}
```

Query in eloquent:

```
$regionlist = = Region::has('regionadv')->get();
```

Good luck.